# Spring Integration graph of Spring Tool Suite not showing "int-file:tail-inbound-channel-adapter" graphic

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-integration, spring-tool-suite

I'm currently using Spring Tool Suite (STS) (Version: 3.6.3.CI-B2266066, Build Id: 201411050946, Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)) with Spring Integration 4.1.0.

I have a Spring configuration XML file that includes the "integration" and "integration/file" namespaces. I've added a "int-file:tail-inbound-channel-adapter" to the config file.  When I go into the integration-graph tab however I'm not seeing the icon/graphic for that component.

Sample config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" 
    xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms" 
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file" 
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">


    <int-file:tail-inbound-channel-adapter id="apache" 
        channel="exchangeSpringQueueChannel" 
        task-executor="exchangeFileReplayTaskExecutor" 
        file="C:\p2-test.txt" 
        delay="1" 
        end="false" 
        reopen="true" 
        file-delay="10000" />

    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="exchangeQueueChannelAdapter" 
        auto-startup="false" 
        destination="exchangeQueueJmsDestination" 
        channel="exchangeSpringQueueChannel"
        receive-timeout="1000" 
        connection-factory="exchangeQueueWMQCachedConnectionFactory" 
        acknowledge="transacted" 
        transaction-manager="exchangeQueueWMQTxManager" 
        error-channel="errorChannel" 
        recovery-interval="20000" 
        task-executor="exchangeQueueReader" />

    <int:channel id="exchangeSpringQueueChannel" />
    <task:executor id="exchangeQueueReader" pool-size="1" />
    <task:executor id="exchangeFileReplayTaskExecutor" pool-size="1" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this; I have created a [JIRA issue against STS](https://jira.spring.io/browse/IDE-1361) for this.