# spring integration file splitter does not appear on the integration-graph

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I have an issue similar to [this problem with items missing from the integration graph.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060459/spring-integration-graph-of-spring-tool-suite-not-showing-int-filetail-inbound) In my case I am using Spring Tool Suite (STS) (Version: 3.9.4, Build Id: 201804120850, Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) with Spring Integration 4.3.15.

I am using a file splitter.  It is working correctly, but does not appear on the integration graph.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                 classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool                  classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context               classpath:org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.3.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration           classpath:org/springframework/integration/config/spring-integration-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream    classpath:org/springframework/integration/stream/config/spring-integration-stream-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file      classpath:org/springframework/integration/file/config/spring-integration-file-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml       classpath:org/springframework/integration/xml/config/spring-integration-xml-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail      classpath:org/springframework/integration/mail/config/spring-integration-mail-4.3.xsd">


<int-file:splitter id="15bfileSplitter" 
        input-channel="PVDR15bChannel"
        output-channel="PVDR15bLineChannel" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. Feel free to raise it here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues